# iOS: Core Data light weight migration is throwing error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

In my 1.0 version of the app, I have created a core data db named "MyApp.sqlite". When I do a core data light weight migration with the same name "MyApp.sqlite", i am getting the below error

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'
, reason: 'Can't modify an immutable model
```

Below is the code

// MARK: - Core Data stack

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {

    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyApp", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    print("hello")
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? =  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyApp.sqlite")
    var err: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]


    NSLog("url =---- \(url)")


    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        err = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()



    }    

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Comment: What actual line of code does it crash on? This code doesn't do anything that corresponds to the error message.

Comment: When I print the value of "self.persistentStoreCoordinator", I am getting "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation...... THIS MIGHT BE THE REASON..

Comment: That's not the question I was asking. If you're getting the error in your question, which line of code causes it?

Comment: I am getting this error, when I try to fetch DB records..... Below is the Code where I am getting this crash:                                                       NSFetchRequest * allItemsRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [allItemsRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                           inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    NSError *error ;
    resultArray = [self executeFetchRequest:allItemsRequest
                                      error:&error];

Comment: Just want to let u know that the coredata db which i created is encrypted. Not sure if this is the reason

Comment: Do you create your model in code or using the Interface Builder model editor? Have you created a versioned `UIManagedObjectModel`?

Comment: I have found a way to resolve this. Thanks.